# Datagridview with report in C#

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datagrid, reportviewer

I have one table with 4 columns (id,nameofcase,priceone,pricetwo) in Mysql.
I made one dataGridView1 with one column and two columns with button for priceone and pricetwo, and i can see the data.
The problem is that, When i pressing one of the two buttons i am getting the information's that i want.
**How to put those information's in the report?**

[image]

```
 private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'lawyerspriceDataSet.lawsuit_under_500' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.lawsuit_under_500TableAdapter.Fill(this.lawyerspriceDataSet.lawsuit_under_500);



        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        { 

            if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["priceoneDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Index)
              {

 //with those 2 lines i am getting the information's that i want

        dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col - 1].Value.ToString();

      dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString();

   }
  else if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["pricetwoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Index)
  {

      dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col - 2].Value.ToString();

      dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString();


  }
}

        }




private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form4 report = new Form4();
            report.Show();
        }
```

Anyone knows how i can do this?

Comment: You do seem to be aware that the DataGridViewCellEventArgs, holds the RowIndex, how is getting data from that row a problem?

Comment: No i dont know the DataGridViewCellEventArgs. In the code i have make a comment that i found it in the web and i test it with that messageBox and it works.

Answer (score 1):

try out this:

```
 private void dataGridview_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridview.Columns["btnName"].Index)
                    {
                        DataGridViewRow dr=dataGridview.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    //do ur stuffs
            }

    }
```

Comment: in line ' if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridview.Columns["btnName"].Index)' it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: have you changed datagridview name and specified proper column name in that string?

Comment: i have change them and the proper column name is priceoneDataGridViewTextBoxColumn and now is ok.But the question was how to When i pressing one of the two buttons i want to take that line with the specific nameofcase and the price and put it on a report so later can print it

Comment: correct me if i am wrong.. u want column 1 value if either button in column 2 and column 3 is clicked?

Comment: column 1 value with column 2 or 3 value depend which column is clicked

Comment: if you want we can chat to explain you

Comment: dude i just told you how to get the row object of which button is clicked... reporting thing you need to do coz i dont know what actually you wanna do.